# How does TypedList in LLBLGEN relate to a database?

Tags: c#, orm, llblgenpro

I have no experience with LLBLGEN. Nevertheless, the company I work for has asked me to use it to do some stuff. They have started me off with this example code

```
var products = new ProductTypedList();
            using (var adapter = new DataAccessAdapter(_Config.ProductionConnectionString)) {
                var testSkn = "172772";
                var filter = new PredicateExpression(ProductFields.Skn == testSkn);
                 adapter.FetchTypedList(products, filter);
            }
```

I have used an ORM before in Django, so I am not completely new to this topic. Anyhow, when I run the code, I notice that the product `172772`  is returned from our product database, which makes sense. My question is, how does the `ProductTypedList` know about that database. I haven't been able to find a connection between it and the database anywhere in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A TypedList is one of the types that a View can generate. (You can also map them to Entities). So a ProductTypedList would normally by the result of a Product View in the database.

The DataAccessAdapter has a parameter that is passing the connection string (that can also be defined in the App or Web.config). Note that the adapter is then used to fetch the TypedList.

Comment: Thank you. My company also said that I should look into using QuerySpec or LinqToLLBLGEN.  Maybe I should make a new question , but what are those things?

Comment: Linq to LLBLGen is the same as Linq to Entity Framework in style: it lets you make queries that look like dbMetaData.TableName.Where(c => c.FieldName == "value").Select(...)   QuerySpec is a piece of LLBLGen I haven't used, but provides a similar Linq experience from what I understand. My preference is for the older LLBLGen native syntax, but that is just a decade of use. It is objectively harder to get started with though, so try them all. Check https://www.llblgen.com/Documentation/ for extensive documentation.